# Match regexp in java

Tags: java, regex

```
String text = "[! hello ¡world ¡] otra cosa ¡]";
String pt = "\\[!(.*)¡\\]";
Matcher mc = Pattern.compile(pt).matcher(text);
while( mc.find() ){
    System.out.println(mc.group(1));
}
```

This code prints `hello ¡world ¡] otra cosa`.

What would be a pattern that matches only `hello ¡world`?

What I don't find is a way to negate a literal string instead of just a char. Something like: `([^(¡\])]*)`

The question is:
How to match everything that is NOT a literal string?

Comment: You may find this link handy when playing with Java regular expressions: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a `?` after the `*`

```
String pt = "\\[!(.*?)¡\\]";
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a *shy* or *reluctant* (*non-greedy*) expression.

See the [documentation for the `java.util.regex.Pattern` class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for the Greedy Quantifier syntax. In your case, you want your Kleene star to match the *shortest string* possible. The normal behavior is greedy: it matches the longest string possible.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your direct question, the way to only match `.` when it is not part of the string `¡]` is to use a negative look-ahead:

```
String pt = "\\[!((?:(?!¡\\]).)*)¡\\]";
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for, matching . that is not ¡] for example. I'll see if it works

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to match the string would be to use negation so that you can avoid .*? which can cause undesirable results and slow performance.

```
String pt = "\[!([^]]*)¡\]";
```

This version will match everything up until it finds the bracket and only backtrack once to match the ¡.

Comment: I assume Franco wants `]` to be matched by the `.` if it isn't preceded by `¡`.